# Auto format , auto new line with Visual Studio Code (on Mac)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using Flutter with Visual Studio Code (on Mac)
I feel uncomfortable with new lines auto added on save[image]

I want to add new lines by myself, like below
[image]

I tried with formatOnSave, but it looks like I got wrong setting to config

```html
"editor.formatOnSave": false
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Prettier as VS-Code default formatter: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode

And then just configure the maximum line width on the plugin settings:

[image]